# Prevent Jenkins Job from escaping the workspace

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

A developer committed a makefile with an output path of ....\SomeDir. When the project was built the output was dumped into Jenkins_Home. Is there any way to fail a build if it attempts to escape the workspace directory? Thanks,
-Michael

Answer (score 1):

Worth putting some strong write permissions in place. Make sure that the user that Jenkins runs as only has permission to write to Jenkins_Home and its subdirectories.

You could also make sure that directories under Jenkins_Home only have write permission if it is necessary (workspace, for logging, etc.)

If a makefile attempts to use an absolute path then the build should fail with a permissions error.

Comment: Additionally to this it is possible to place the workspaces in a separate directory by setting the 'Workspace Root Directory' in the jenkins options (under the advanced button). This should allow you to only give the jenkins user access to the Jenkins_Home directory and the workspace directory but at the same time having the workspace directory not being a sub-directory of the Jenkins_Home directory. E.g. Jenkins_Home = c:\jenkins and the workspace directory = c:\workspaces

Comment: That would prevent the job from writing into an arbitrary directory. It doesn't prevent what happened in this case; the job wrote into Jenkins_Home.

Comment: Can you not make the Jenkins_Home directory read only? Does anything need to write to it?

Comment: Jenkins needs to write to the logs and configuration files in the Jenkins_Home directory so unfortunately you can't make it read-only to the Jenkins user, hence my earlier suggestion.

Comment: Another solution would be to never build on the Jenkins master and have a bunch of build slaves. In that case you can set the permissions on the workspaces only.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is that, before running the command, to do a change directory to workspace. If you have the workspace set up, then you can write something like cd $WORKSPACE or cd %WORKSPACE% ( for batch commands).